# How can I configure shutdown, reboot etc. to display a message on an old (2.6) Linux?

Tags: linux, init

I have an old embedded control system that still uses a 2.6 kernel and runs Debian 4.

I am looking for a way to display a message whenever the superuser calls (interactively) reboot, shutdown, poweroff or halt. The message only needs to appear on the interactive terminal that the command is sent from.

Essentially, I want to replace the classic "The system is going down for system halt NOW!"

Is there an easy way to configure those binaries to do that, or will I need to resort to writing ugly wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown and so on usually progress through `telinit` setting the runlevel to 6 or 0, and this calls the kill scripts in `/etc/rc6.d/K*` so you could add a `wall` command to one of those scripts in the `stop` section.